# Using Microsoft NLB, is there a way to route certain traffic to different servers?

Tags: azure, nlb

I have a situation where I have some microservices that do some work that I would like offloaded to different servers.  I currently use Microsofts' built-in NLB  for web traffic and that seems to work fine, but I would like to take traffic destined for certain urls and route them to a different server to get them off the main web servers.    I am thinking I need something like ARR installed but the documents I can find are pretty confusing and not sure if that is needed.   I was talking with another person and he was thinking that should be built into NLB but I can't find anything about that.

So basically, if traffic is going to '...//mysite.com/services', I would like that traffic routed to a different server; all other traffic should go to my main web server.

Where would be the best place for me to start?

Answer (score 0):

Azure has several load balancing services

- Load Balancer
- Traffic manager
- Azure Front Door
- Application Gateway

The one that appears to fit your requirements is the Application Gateway since it allows for routing of requests based on URI path.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview